# Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use.

Tags: appium

Could not start REST http interface listener. The requested port may already be in use. Please make sure there is no other instance of this server running already.

Answer (score 2):

Kill node.exe using below steps :

1. Open command prompt and issue `taskkill /F /IM node.exe`
2. Rerun the test

Or you can simply kill Node.js process from Task Manager.